# Undefined reference to existing method

Tags: android, c++, c, cyanogenmod

I am trying to compile CyanogenMod 10.2 for my device, but I get a compilation error while compiling frameworks/av:

```
target SharedLib: libmediaplayerservice (/home/vektor/CM102/out/target/product/s7300b  /obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmediaplayerservice_intermediates/LINKED/libmediaplayerservice.so)
frameworks/av/media/libmediaplayerservice/AmlogicPlayer.cpp:891: error: undefined reference to 'ammodule_match_check(char const*, char const*)'
```

That method is declared in `ammodule.h` contained in `/device/my/device/packages/LibPlayer/amavutils/include`

And in `AmlogicPlayer.cpp` it's included:

```
#include "ammodule.h"
```

In `Android.mk` the file seems included:

```
AMPLAYER_APK_DIR=$(TOP)/device/my/device/packages/LibPlayer/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES +=\
    $(AMPLAYER_APK_DIR)/amavutils/include
```

This is the signature from `ammodule.h`

```
int ammodule_match_check(const char *allmodstr,const char *modname);
```

Everything seems ok. What could cause such errors?

Answer (score 1):

The function signiture refers to

```
const char *
```

Whereas the c++ file is looking for a function with

```
char const*
```

These are not the same thing. One is a constant pointer to a non-constant char, whereas the other is a non-constant pointer to a constant char.
Google const char* vs char const* for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not caused by `const char*` and `char const *` because they are all the same. `const char *` and `char * const` are different things. Further more, if the signature mis-matches, the compiler, instead of the linker will complain.

I suggest that you check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and the -l option in your Android.mk to see if the error disappears.